# "fallback" http server

Tags: linux, web-server

I have a web application, which is served by a standalone app. Sometimes the JVM it's running in crashes, but most often, I need to take it down to deploy a new version or to update the system. For various reasons it has to serve HTTP/HTTPS requests directly, so I can't use a proxy in front of it.

Is there some way to have the system itself (Ubuntu Linux) answer HTTP requests when the app is down? Or, in other words, is there some way to configure the server so that whenever the normal response would be "connection refused", it would serve some static (503) page instead? If possible, it would be great if it could handle HTTPS as well.

Comment: What's doing your actual web serving?

Comment: it's a custom app doing its own web serving..

Comment: If it is a custom app, it may have a custom setting for this. If not, you might be able to script something to send requests to the server and based on the response, take actions. Say if it does not receive a response, it could then shut it down and pull up a backup server app (a lamp stack or nginx or anything else) that has a basic version of the site to use while the main one is down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use **[haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/)** in tcp mode to transparently proxy the requests. Your application server won't know the difference, *except* that the remote ip will be the localhost. It will return an error to the client if it can't contact the backend server by default. You can also specify a backup server, to which requests are routed to when the backend goes down.

If you truly want to avoid any "proxy", you could use iptables to redirect the ports. You would run a server like nginx to serve the error files on an unused port. With a monitoring script (or a daemon like [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/)), you could redirect the application's port to your error server with a rule like:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp \
--dport $SVC_PORT -j REDIRECT --to-port $ERROR_PORT
```

Your monitoring system would need to dynamically insert or delete the rules as the availability of services change.

Comment: I was just about to suggest the same thing!  The backup server could even be running on the same physical server as the default server, either running a separate instance of the web server, or a different web server entirely.

Comment: @Joe - yes, I've often used a local nginx instance (simply because of its tiny resource usage) as the backup server for custom error pages.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, haproxy looks like a neat tool. But, like I said - I can't really use a proxy in front of the app. The solution, if it exists, would have to involve the kernel/OS in some way, I guess..

Comment: @xs0 - can you explain *why* you can't use a proxy? It makes it hard to offer solutions when we don't know what the restrictions are

Comment: My app is a SaaS thing and the configuration of the whole set-up is constantly changing (based on what its users are doing), including IPs that are listened on, domains that are served, SSL certificates, etc. Unless you know of a proxy that can do this (i.e. be run-time-configurable without restarting)?

Comment: @xs0 - yes, haproxy.

Comment: how can you tell haproxy to change configuration in runtime? I'm thinking of something like an API that my app could call, not generating a huge configuration file every time something changes..

Comment: The iptables rule you suggested seems closer to what I'm looking for, but I think nat will mangle client IPs, which is very undesirable (security), and also has to be turned on/off, which will always be delayed compared to the "optimal" time.. Can you tell iptables to only do this redirect if the original response to a connection request would've been "connection refused"?

Comment: @xs0 - haproxy will accept commands over a unix port, but you can only get stats, and change the status of services that are already configured. To add new services, you would have to modify the config file, but it is not huge nor is it hard to parse.

Comment: @xs0 - The rule in my example is not masquerading the address, simply redirecting the port. I don't know what you mean by "`and also has to be turned on/off, which will always be delayed compared to the "optimal" time`". Iptables isn't "on" or "off", you insert and delete rules as needed. Iptables also can't predict the future, and redirect the packets if the connection would be refused.

Comment: First, sorry for my unclear comment. if the address is not being masqueraded, then that's cool, it seems I was assuming that the "nat" parameter means more than it does.. by on/off I was referring to the rule, not iptables as a whole.. also, I don't think there is a need to predict the future :) The way I'd like it to work is this: when a TCP connection is being established, the client sends a packet requesting a connection. If there is nothing to accept it, the OS will return a "connection refused" packet. What I'd like it to do instead is redirect the connection to something else..

Comment: @xs0 - I've offered two ways to accomplish this. You can either do this at the application layer (haproxy or similar), or at the network level (iptables). What you're asking is for something that will catch an ICMP port-unreachable packet (from layer 3) in reply to a TCP-SYN packet (layer 4), somehow finish the setup of a TCP session (SYN-ACK, ACK), then send an HTTP 503 (layer 7) to the client. Do you see why this is crazy? Monitoring the service, and preemptively redirecting the traffic makes much more sense.

Comment: @JimB - I wouldn't call it crazy, just unusual. There's no need to catch the ICMP packet and then do weird stuff, the idea was that something else happens instead of the packet being sent. If the OS supported this, it could be done in a perfectly "clean" way. I guess the rule could easily be described as "if a TCP connection attempt to port X would fail because nobody is listening, try port Y before sending port-unreachable". But, I guess Linux doesn't support this yet, so I guess that short of kernel hacking, I can't do it. Maybe I should finally take a look at the kernel code :)

Comment: @xs0 - I understand the result you want, but that decision to redirect the port isn't part of the TCP/IP spec, and there's no provision for the client to be able to handle this. If you want to translate the port number on the fly, that's what iptables is for. If you want to proxy the stream, and try to connect it to different ports, that's what a load-balancer like haproxy is for. This doesn't have anything to do with the kernel. Linux does support this - I'm running many haproxy instances in production on Linux, and I do what you're asking all  the time.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this directly (I.E. if the app is down, the app is down and will not return anything, even an error)
You can, however, run something like NGINX which can send custom errors if the main server is down or if it returns an error.